# PHP write to file from included script file

Tags: php, include, fwrite

I have one script, let's call it "main" php script, there is another script, call it "writer". And I have a xml file. My "writer" get's info from db and writes it to the xml. All work fine if I execute my writer directly.

Right now I want to execute "writer" from my "main" script. The problem is, that I can see my output from writer file in my main (I add some echo's for testing purposes), but it doesn't rewrite my xml file like it does when I execute it directly.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Code from main:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include_once("./../writer.php");


    $_SESSION['make_sitemap'] = true;

    echo 'ok';

?>
```

Code from writer:

```
<?php
session_start();
// include some utility files and header, also connection to db    

if($_SESSION['make_sitemap']){ 

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

// some boring stuff with xml variable 


$fp = fopen('./myxml.xml', 'w');

fwrite($fp, $xml, strlen($xml));

fclose($fp);

echo 'done';

}

?>
```

Thats all folks, nothing extraordinary, I think. But hmm why it doesn't rewrite, I don't know.

Comment: As others stand to comment, posted `code` is always a given.

Comment: Some code would be nice, otherwise I lack the ability to read your question and image at the same time

Comment: ok, ok you want it you got it:)

Comment: ^---- Reminds me of an `~AC-DC~` song.

Comment: @Fred heh, I just remembered it from GTA San Andreas gun shop :), also I add the code.

Comment: @flinth Have you tried `include` instead of `include_once`?

Comment: @Fred nope, few secs and I will

Comment: @flinth Go for it, keep me posted.

Comment: @Fred nope, this doesn't made a thing

Comment: @Fred may be there is a problem in permissions?

Comment: @flinth Maybe. Are they set at 644 right now, or 777?

Comment: at the time you include your file, the session variable hasn't been set yet, so the file writing code will never execute... as written, this'd only work the SECOND time you run the code.

Comment: @Fred it's 644 right now

Comment: @MarcB hmmm may be I don't know about this precisely, this don't cause a problem for me right now, but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative Paths in php are resolved based where they are executed, meaning where ever the file that php originally starting running the request with.  This means that when you hit your `writer.php` directly it means that `./myxml.xml` will appear in the same directory that you writer.php lives in likewise with main.php.

A better bet would be to establish a common place that all paths would be relative to like `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`.

so instead of

```
./myxml.xml
```

you would say

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/path/to/my/myxml.xml"
```

If this becomes too tedious you can define a couple of known locations in a common include like.

```
define("XML_PATH", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/path/to/my");
```

then use it as

```
XML_SAVE_PATH."/myxml.xml"
```

Comment: You are perfectly right, I will consider it next time. Thank you and all who tried to help me!